# ECDsa instance is not usable when a private key is imported a second time

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm having no trouble creating an instance of `ECDsa` and importing a private key via `ImportECPrivateKey`; however, if the original instance is Disposed AND a new instance is created AND the same private key is imported, it fails with an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Here's my repo code:

```cs
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ECDsaDisposeBug;

public class JwtSigningKeyProvider : IDisposable
{
    const string privateKeyBase64 = "MIHcAgEBBEIAsukFBinjgL9KONxPRvunQGdaTEhIL9JpwlgW0NN0XzlmbENucgw4XTczjyjlF9AnJnJHg8vXoM2bH5MJy+42OeegBwYFK4EEACOhgYkDgYYABAF8Nt5oxNZ9VwQzjPCWai7/p8hI6sbCAQI8wDcWfQ2Cddrw4G7v5wu6+z26hGJSJY66wKl0ar4fN+JrbCMIYS9UugHAs3W75a/KtiNfVJ9tYwFM0CYWP2kAKg7Kbk3SXkXMW4Gdb4XeoDO+TQVTRfWoBYXXx1iVu0dOXv5NkGZFIkKAHg==";
    readonly ECDsa algorithm = ECDsa.Create();

    public AsymmetricSecurityKey Get()
    {
        var privateKey = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyBase64);
        algorithm.ImportECPrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKey), out _);
        return new ECDsaSecurityKey(algorithm);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        algorithm.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // This works fine the first time
        var provider = new JwtSigningKeyProvider();
        var key = provider.Get();
        AssertKeyIsUsable(key);
        provider.Dispose();

        // It fails the second time with an ObjectDisposed exception
        provider = new JwtSigningKeyProvider();
        key = provider.Get();
        AssertKeyIsUsable(key);
        provider.Dispose();
    }
    private static void AssertKeyIsUsable(AsymmetricSecurityKey key)
    {
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);
        var securityDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
        };
        var tokenHandler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityDescriptor);       // This will throw if there's a problem with the key
        Assert.NotNull(token);
    }
}
```

I have [reported this to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/99605), but I was hoping someone on SO has a work-around.